# NerdDinner MVC and Html.Encode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nerddinner

In `DinnerController` I got a data.[image]

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
 {

            Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);

            if (dinner == null)
                return View("NotFound");
            else
                return View("Details", dinner);
  }
```

and in `details.aspx` I bound it like this.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Details</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            DinnerID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.DinnerID) %>
        </p>
        </fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

but I got a error.
`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DinnerID' and no extension method 'DinnerID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.
I just start to learn `mvc` and unable to understand the problem.May I missing something.Plz help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to check the check box `Create a strongly-typed view` when create a view show i got this error.i solve this through adding `<HelloMvc.Models.Dinner>` in `details.aspx` page.
Means when I got error code like this.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

After solve the problem code becames:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HelloMvc.Models.Dinner>" %>
```

Thanks for reply.I post this ans for future ref.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing several things wrong : 
1) It is called MVC meaning Model View Controller( your Dinner entity is passed to your view through your  controller )
What you are trying to make is a new View . It will be Created in the View section of your project.

I think this code might show you what you need :

```
@model HelloMvc.Models.Dinner  //passing the value of dinner is done here . from now on you will refer to the dinner object with Model
<table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           Description
         </td>
         <td>
            @Html.Display(Model.Description) //google other @Html diplay modes ( Label Textbox, etc)
         </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

MVC can be hard at first especially if you developed a Asp.Net thinking; be patient and understand the basic concepts at first and you will love it.
 Here's a link that will help you understand the entire process. 
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2011/06/03/asp.net-mvc-3-creating-a-simple-sign-up-form.aspx